# send list of database rows like object to view in nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, express

I'm new in `nodejs` and `expressjs` I want to do some query on my database table and show the result in view but i cant do it:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mysql = require('mysql');
var con = mysql.createConnection({
 host: "localhost",
 user: "root",
 password: "",
 database: "imanweb"
});

/* GET home page. */ 
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
let objects=['a','b']
con.connect(function(err){
 if(err) throw err;
 con.query("select * from tags", function (err, result) {
 if (err) throw err;
 result.forEach(function(element) {
 objects.push(element);
 console.log("Result: " + element.title);
  }, this);

  });
 })
 console.log("Array: " + objects);
 res.render('index', { title: 'Express' ,objs:objects});
});

module.exports = router;
```

actually the log of this code is like this:

```
   Arr:a,b
    Get 200 /410.25 ms --196
    Result:php
    Result:.net
```

so it seems the last line of my code is running sooner as the past lines(query)!

it's some thing like asynchronous code running!. so when i give `objects` to `objs` parameter. there is no query result inside that.

as solution I tried to use `then()` but i got `> undefined` then error in my code..

How can I handle that ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put your `res.render` function inside the callback. Like this:

```
con.connect(function(err){
  if(err) throw err;
  result.forEach(function(element) {
    objects.push(element);
  }
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' ,objs:objects});
}, this);
```

If you send the response outside the callback, your response will be send immediately - it will not wait for the async function.

Comment: Then you'll have to nest the callbacks. Or - as I would recommend - use a promise library. Then you can do `then` and `catch` - and avoid nested callbacks within nested callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

This works? If not try use `async` module to do this `forEach` method in your code.
I've this issue one time and the problem was on forEach.